# Build step in notification

Tags: drone.io

I would like to display which build step(s ?) failed in our slack notification. 
I couldn't find any reference here http://plugins.drone.io/drone-plugins/drone-slack/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try using the *when* clause on *failure* condition

`notify:
  slack:
    channel: foo
    when:
      success: false
      failure: true
      change: true`

here is the complete reference and example on drone notification
[drone notify](http://readme.drone.io/0.4/usage/notify/)